Prior to 2024, had Israel ever directly attacked any other government embassy/consulate?
In 2024, Israel attacked the Iranian Embassy in Damascus as shown here
Is the first time Israel has directly attacked the embassy/consulate of another country? If not, when was the last time?

Interestingly enough, just came out today: Argentina court blames Iran for deadly 1994 bombing of Jewish center.  As far as I know, that's what started their bad blood (remember Israel's involvement in the Iran-Contra affair)  That was not in an embassy, but then again Iran has form wrt embassies...  That said, it's unusual for a state to deliberately attack an embassy as that's a casus belli with the embassy country and the host country (2-for-1 in terms of blowback).

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica in that (opposite) direction the list is surely longer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_attacks_against_Israeli_embassies_and_diplomats

@DogBoy37: right after they conquered Moscow?

Does this count as direct attack? https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/56576/61574

@C.F.G: it wasn't an embassy. UK gov't building, sure.

According to the relevant Wikipedia list, no, there is no precedent by the State of Israel. But an extremist Jewish group bombed the Czech and Soviet embassies in Tel Aviv in the 1950s. There were no deaths though, but 3 are listed as injured in the Soviet embassy [bombing] case. The article on the group has more details:

On February 9, 1953, the group planted more than 70 pounds of explosives at the Soviet embassy. The ensuing explosion severely injured the embassy's housekeeper and significantly damaged the embassy building. Two other embassy employees were also lightly hurt, one of them the Soviet ambassador's wife. The USSR cut diplomatic relations with Israel in response. The bomb was planted by Yosef Menkes, who later planned the assassination of Rudolf Kastner. The sophistication of the bombing led Shin Bet head Isser Harel to believe that former Lehi members were responsible, but an intensive investigation failed to turn up the perpetrators.
[...] Although the government was unable to prove the group's involvement in the Soviet embassy attack, [judge] Halevy nevertheless deemed the group "a severe danger to state security".

AFAICT, they were sentenced for bombing an Israeli ministry [or belonging to a group that did that], but

two years later, they were freed, and Prime Minister David Ben-Gurion commuted their sentences.

FWTW, the Soviets justified breaking off relations then by accusing the Israeli state of 'connivance' in the attack:

“The apologies of the Israeli Government have been contradicted by numerous facts of direct participation by the Israeli Government in fanning hatred for the Russian Government and in inciting hostile actions against Russia,” the Soviet Union says in an official statement released through the Tass news agency. The statement cites “the obvious connivance of the Israeli police” in the bombing. [...]
The Netherlands represents Israeli interests in Moscow during the diplomatic break. Israel and the Soviet Union announce the resumption of diplomatic relations July 21, 1953, while Israeli promises to find and punish the bombers.

The West-German embassy in Tel Aviv was also 'occupied' by two Israeli protesters in 1977, and again in 1978:

Three Israeli gunmen seized the West German Embassy and Culture Centre in Tel Aviv. They demanded the abolition of the West German statute of limitations whereby those accused of war crimes could not be tried after 1978.

If you're willing to go slightly before the actual/formal creation of State of Israel, you could add the 1946 bombing of British Embassy in Rome, by Irgun--a paramilitary Zionist force.
Conversely, Israeli embassies were attacked on fairly numerous occasions.
